# Execute stored procedure on DB1 using DB2 data

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to execute a stored procedure in `DB1` using data that exists in `DB2`?

`DB1` (test DB) contains all necessary tables and schema is the same as in `DB2` (Production DB).

I have tried searching for an answer for a while but couldn't find anything.

I do have linked server set up for `DB2`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is it a test environment that you want to use production data in? Or both of the environments are production?

Comment: I am trying to run the SP in test environment using production data if that is possible.

Comment: I guess there is no way other than go into the SP and change all to point to the production DB?

Comment: Ok, I would highly recommend (very high) not to link those two! Just take a prod backup, restore it into a test environment and deploy your scripts. Or you can set up a basic export in SSMS or ssis to move the data to a test environment.

Comment: Yes it is possible, however, what is the issue, can you explain more, because this is similar to a circular reference in programming and does not make much sense?

Comment: Are you allowed to write your own SP in the test instance?

Comment: Can you please show us an example of the query and data you're trying to work with, and the expected result/output of the query?